# probability question on a customer

Tags: probability, statistics

A very frustrated customer is trying to find an electronic receipt on their phone so they can return an item. The trouble is that the customer has three email accounts and can't remember which, one, account it was sent to. The customer assumes that there is an equal probability for each account. To add complexity the phone only has enough battery power to search one of the three email accounts

Unfortunately, the store says that this is the last day it will accept the return, and it is only 3 minutes till close, so there will not be any chance to get to a charger. The customer randomly decides to search one of the emails, without any bias.

Suppose, due to the organization and the various spam filters of the accounts, the chance of finding the receipt even if they were to search in the correct account is not a guarantee. The probability of finding it in account 1, assuming it was sent there is 62%, 54% if in account 2 and 56% for account 3.

**Part (a) What is the probability that if the receipt is in account 2 that the customer will find it?**

I think this one is (1/3)*(0.54) 
The third is for choosing the account and then times 0.54 is the prob for finding from the question. but the question seems like a conditional probability so I'm not sure.

**Part (b) Calculate the probability the receipt was in account 2, if the search in account 2 is unsuccessful.**

I think this one is ((1/3)(0.16))/((1/3)(0.31)+(1/3)(0.16)+(1/3)(0.49))

**Part(c) What is the probability this person finds the email?**

(1/3)(0.69)+(1/3)(0.84)+(1/3)(0.51) because we can either find it in account 1 or 2 or 3

Any help would  be appreciated!

Comment: Please use MathJax to format https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I agree with your answers to (a) and (c), although I'll have to think about (b)

Comment: For account 1 is it 62% or 69%?  And for account 2 is it 54% or 84%? ANd for account 3 is it 56% or 51%?

Comment: @Bram28 didn't spot that myself. Yes, good point.

Comment: I think I put the wrong numbers

Comment: Could you explain your (b) answer?

Comment: I used the wrong numbers for b too. sorry. but what I should have had is (1/3)*(0.46) for not finding it in account 2. Over not finding it at all in all three (1/3)(0.38)+(1/3)(0.46)+(1/3)(0.44)

Comment: but I think the denominator is not correct

Comment: It should be just (1/3)(0.46) because the given for the conditional is that the search was unsuccessful in 2 only

Comment: @Justagirl to say that the search was unsuccessful in 2 is to say that you did search account 2, but did not find it. Now why did you not find it? Well, it could have been in account 2, but you didn't find it. The chance of that is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0.46$. but it could also be because it was in account 1, so of course you didn't find it when searching 2. THe probability of that is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1$. Same for account 3.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! I understand!

Comment: @Justagirl Another way of looking at this is that intially, the chance of the receipt being in account 2 is the same as it being in account 1 or 3: $\frac{1}{3}$. However, after searching 2 and not finding it, the chances of it being in account 2 should be decreased by quite a bit, but with your original formula, it would still be around $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For b) you should get:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0.46}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 0.46 +\frac{1}{3}}$$

The denominator is the chance of it not finding the receipt in account 2 when searching account 2. So if it is in account 1 or 3, you are certain to not find it when searching account 2.

Comment: +1 - I agree with this. The denominator represents all of the cases where you can be unsuccessful. If you search in ac 2 while the receipt is in ac 1, then you are going to fail all the time, and likewise if it is in 3.